# "Children Of Miracles" quote

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, christianity

UPDATE: I reached out to one of the ministries listed below and was told that this was said by RABBI SCHNEERSON.

So if anyone knows of a message, whether printed/published or audio/video, of Rabbi Schneerson, aka Rebbe, making comments like those listed below, that would probably be what I am looking for. Especially is it includes him using the phrase "children of miracles" as that seems to be the common phrase of both quotes.

---

I am wondering if anyone can help me identify source information for two similar quotes I have heard by Christian Pastors, stating that the quotes are from "a famous rabbi"

The first is from a book titled 'Unveiling Ancient Biblical Secrets' by Pastor Larry Huch, where he says:

"That famous rabbi went on to say that the Messiah is ready to come, but first, something else will happen: there will be a group of Gentiles (non-Jews) whose eyes will be opened in order to understand Jewish teachings such as Passover, Shabbat, Rosh Hashanah, and Yom Kippur. At first, those around them will think it strange, but then, these Gentiles will begin to see such miracles and blessings of God in a way that draws the attention of the entire world. Those whose eyes will be opened will be called "the children of miracles.""

Pastor Huch's book is available on Google in preview if you would like to view the entire page this was stated on for context.

The other is a quote from Pastor Rod Parsley who made a similar claim/statement/quote in a message delivered from his Church. Parsley stated:

"A prominent Jewish rabbi was teaching ten thousand rabbis, and here's what he said, "Messiah is ready to come right now. But just prior, a group of Gentile's eyes will be opened regarding four cups and miracles associated with Passover. They will be called "the children of miracles."""

I assume these statements would have been made by the same Rabbi, but neither Pastor gave reference to who said these things. I am hoping, assuming that these are legitimate quotes made by a Jewish Rabbi, that someone on this group may be able to help me identify the source and even the original documentation of these quotes. I would love to study this out in the context of the full message(s) that these statements were given in.

Blessings and Shalom

Tom

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Tom and thanks for this first question. Please note that not all questions are [in-scope](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site, notably questions about what others wrote about Judaism are out of scope and likely to be closed. Please do not be offended by this.

Comment: Unless they give a real citation, it sounds like the usual claims of of other religions. There have been groups that seem to make these claims about themselves, but you should write the people who said this and ask for details.

Comment: UPDATE: I reached out to one of the ministries listed below and was told that this was said by RABBI SCHNEERSON. 

So if anyone knows of a message, whether printed/published or audio/video, of Rabbi Schneerson, aka Rebbe, making comments like those listed below, that would probably be what I am looking for. Especially is it includes him using the phrase "children of miracles" as that seems to be the common phrase of both quotes.